# java object not compiled

Tags: java, oop

I have following java code segment,

```
class Box{
    int length;
    int width;
    int height;

    Box(int length, int width, int height){
        this.length=length;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }
    Box(){
        this.length=1;
        this.width=1;
        this.height=1;
    }
}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Box b1=new Box(); //calling default
        System.out.println("Length : "+b1.length);
        System.out.println("Width  : "+b1.width);
        System.out.println("Height : "+b1.height);

        b1.Box(12,5,3);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

but when I compile the java file following code highlight and not the compile
`b1.Box(12,5,3);`

what is the problem and how can fix this?

Comment: `b1 = new Box(12,5,3);`?

Comment: Constructors are not methods.

Comment: `b1.length=12;b1.width=5;b1.height=3;`

Comment: Why not just call the parameterized constructor "directly" in the first place? Why even bother with the default constructor?

Answer (score 0):

`Box(12,5,3)` is a parameterized constructor and not a method of `Box` class, hence there no need to call it using a reference. Just call it directly without using the object.

Therefore, instead of declaring `b1` with the default constructor you can use the parameterized one as follows:

```
Box b1 = new Box(12, 5, 3);
```

Or you can create a setter function in the `Box` class if you need to set the values later as

```
public void setDimensions(int length, int width, int height) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
```

then `b1.Box(12,5,3);` becomes `b1.setDimensions(12,5,3);`